# How to develop my code using another commit but without incorporating that into my patch

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm attempting to develop my own code on my own development branch `D`. I can't test with `master` code because someone recently introduced a bug (call that commit `B`) that interferes with my code. Now, while they work to fix their bug and move their code forward, some other kind soul has posted a patch to our Gerrit server, `R`, that reverts patch `B`. So, I have the option to use cherry-pick or download or pull or format-patch to get hold of `R`, and if I do so, I can develop and test my own code quite well.

The problem is that at some point I am going to want to submit my own patch for review. I don't want to interfere with anyone else's files, so I don't want the changes in `R` to be included in my own commit.

What I've been doing is:

1. edit my own code
2. commit my changes to development branch `D`
3. use `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to squish these changes with my previous work
4. cherry-pick the revert patch `R`
5. build and test my code
6. use `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to cut commit `R` out of my local code
7. (now I'm free to either push my changes or go back to #1 and iterate)

My question is, can I cut steps #4 and #6 out of this workflow and still get back to something that I can push without interfering with the other efforts to fix bug `B`?

At present there is no overlap between the files involved in `R` and my own work, and I don't *think* that is likely to change.

Comment: If there is no overlap among the files you and your team members are working on, I do not see a problem. Eventually, git will compare the file content you touched to the master when you create a pull request. I am assuming that your team is using pull requests for all commits.

Comment: The problem with submitting files including `R` is that it's going to conflict with their eventual fix. If they submit a fix first, I will have to resolve the conflict, and vice versa. Looking at it another way, I don't have authority to change their files, and I should not be doing so.

Comment: I see. If there will be a conflict when you are committing your code, you need to re-sync the code of that file from their branch or master if it has been merged. You can use cherry-pick to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution may be to simply continue working with the changes in `R` in my local repository, and before I finally submit my code for review, cherry-pick patch `B` again. That should put their files back the way they are on master, meaning that my patch will only change my files. And it doesn't matter whether I submit this code before or after the other team submits a fix for their bug, because my patch doesn't touch their code.